Inherit type of parameters from class
We have a class with some users and we need to type it using interfaces.
class User {
   name: string = '';
   lastName: string = '';
   age: number = 18;
   isAdmin: boolean = false;

   constructor(props) {
      if (props?.name) this.name = props.name;
      if (props?.lastName) this.lastName = props.lastName;
      if (props?.age) this.age = props.age;
      if (props?.isAdmin) this.isAdmin= props.isAdmin;
   }

    add(key, value) {
       this[key] = value;
    }
}

The first interface will describe the types that come to our constructor and will look like this:
interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  age?: number;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
}

The second interface should describe the parameters that come in add method. Types in the second interface must inherit from the type described in the IUser interface. How can we implement this?

I'm not sure I understand. What interface do you expect? Your method expects two parameters, so you would need two interfaces (one per parameter). What would the interface look like if you simply typed it out (without "inheriting", just copying the code to mirror what you would expect)?

Offtopic: class User is not OOP, it is complicated procedural coding disguised as OOP. It makes more harm than good. Drop the pseudo-class User, keep the interface IUser and the code will become less bloated, more clear and using the same amount of "OOP" as before (i.e. not at all.)

interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  age?: number;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
}
class User {
   name: string = '';
   lastName: string = '';
   age: number = 18;
   isAdmin: boolean = false;

   constructor(props: IUser) {
      if (props?.name) this.name = props.name;
      if (props?.lastName) this.lastName = props.lastName;
      if (props?.age) this.age = props.age;
      if (props?.isAdmin) this.isAdmin= props.isAdmin;
   }

    add<K extends keyof IUser>(key: K, value: this[K]) {
       this[key] = value;
    }
}

const myUser = new User({});
myUser.add('name', '123');
myUser.add('age', 123);
myUser.add('age', '123'); // type error

I think generic could solve this problem, by using extends keyof IUser, you can define mapping relation between two parameters

• I would suggest making value of type this[K] instead of IUser[K] and you can avoid the type assertion. • While this code may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion..

You can extend the IUser interface as you would do with a class (you can find out more here):
interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  age?: number;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
}

interface IUserExtended extends IUser {
  [key: string]: any;
}

